# google task api authentication issue

Tags: php, google-api

I am using the Google calendar API in a PHP script to get the list of upcoming events. I am using a service account which works well.

Now I also wanted to call the Tasks API and it behaves differently regarding the authentication.

Credentials that work for Calendar API:

```
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($client_email, $scopes, $private_key, 'notasecret','http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer', 'example@gmail.com');
```

I can get all the events for the user 'example@gmail.com' this way. When I use these credentials for the Tasks API, I get this:

> "error" : "unauthorized_client", "error_description" : "Unauthorized client or scope in request."

If I remove the user I want to query, 'example@gmail.com' in this example, I can query the service account's tasks, which is not really what I want.

Any suggestions?